# on/off switching xml attribute state

Tags: javascript, html, xml, switch-statement, toggle

Hi to the sof community,

I have a specific need, but I don't handle enough js and ajax or socket.io yet to perform it I guess.

This is it, I need to write a web page on the client side with a switch which would generate a simple xml on the server setting an attribute according to its position.

Here is my structure :

```
<html>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <label class="switch switch-green">
      <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" checked>
      <span class="switch-label" data-on="On" data-off="Off"></span>
      <span class="switch-handle"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and I would like to generate a simple xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<starter>
  <switch>0</switch>
 </starter>
```

writing 0 or 1 depending on switch state.
My goal is then to rule an other js script to push a `xmlhttp.open("GET", , )` to present data to the client.

I wish your lights would assist me to reach it...
Where should I start to perform this operation, is that a proper approach ?
I am open to any suggestion.

Comment: could you pls post your workouts

Comment: Do you have something serverside that can generate xml?

Answer (score 0):

First I am looking to make it works locally, and find a way to edit my file.xml in the main folder.
I red a lot about xml dom on W3C, but I didn't succeed to change the switch value passing by an html interface.

Actually this is where I am presently :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <head>
    <style>

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

      <div class="container">

        <label class="switch switch-green">
          <input id="starter" name="starter" type="checkbox" onclick="checkin()" class="switch-input"/>
          <span class="switch-label" data-on="On" data-off="Off"></span>
          <span class="switch-handle"></span>
        </label>
      </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }


    function checkin() {
            if (document.getElementById('starter').checked) {
                alert("checked");
            } else {
                alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.");
            }
        }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Conditions work fine now, but I would like to switch between passing 1 or 0 into a file like switch_state.xml

EDIT:

Here is my shot with xml dom, just to notice I have backed up the loadxmldoc.js from :
https://code.google.com/p/sail-web-vle/source/browse/trunk/vle/js/common/loadxmldoc.js?r=3
and saved it under a js folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">

    <label class="switch switch-green">
      <input id="starter" name="starter" type="checkbox" onclick="checkin()" class="switch-input"/>
      <span class="switch-label" data-on="On" data-off="Off"></span>
      <span class="switch-handle"></span>
    </label>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/loadxmldoc.js">

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }


function checkin() {
        if (document.getElementById('starter').checked) {
            //alert("checked");
        xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc('switch_state.xml');
        x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("switch")[0].childNodes[0];
        x.nodeValue="bleah";
        document.write(x.nodeValue);

        } else {
            // alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.");
        xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc('switch_state.xml');
        x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("switch")[0].childNodes[0];
        x.nodeValue="yipikayeah";
        document.write(x.nodeValue);
        }
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<starter>
  <switch>"off"</switch>
</starter>
```

But nothing happened if checkbox is checked or not...